# Looping an object

Tags: php, object, foreach, model

Using object model I can output individual item data like so:

```
$order->items[0]->item_qty -- For item 1
$order->items[1]->item_qty -- For item 2

$order->items[0]->entry_id -- For item 1
$order->items[1]->entry_id -- For item 2
```

As I wont know how many items are in the object, I can't have [0] or [1]. I would like to therefore loop through somehow, but I am unsure how this would work with a foreach statement.

Could anyone show me how this could be done?

**EDIT**

```
foreach ($order as $obj) {
   print_r($obj->items->item_qty);
}
```

Gives the following error:

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looping through all the properties of object php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976624/looping-through-all-the-properties-of-object-php)

Comment: Why don't you iterate over items ? items is an array so if you have object in items[someIndex] you can retrieve property, but if you don't you have an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a foreach the way it is meant:

```
foreach($order->items as $item) {
    $item->item_qty;
    $item->entry_id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this then shows the error:  Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `foreach`

```
foreach ($objects as $obj) 
{
    foreach($obj as $item)
    {
        echo $item->item_qty;
        echo "<br>".$item->entry_id;
    }
}
```

**OR**

```
    foreach($order->items as $item) {
    echo $item->item_qty;
    echo "<br>".$item->entry_id
 }
```

Source: [How to loop through objects in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664208/how-to-loop-through-objects-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

use `count();`

ex:

```
$size = count($order->items);
for ($i=0 ; $i<$size ; $i++) {
    $order->items[$i]->entry_id // For item 1
    $order->items[$i]->entry_id // For item 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Where as `items` is also an array so you need to loop over items something like

```
foreach($order->items as $item) {
    echo  $item->qty;
    echo  $item->entry_id;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
foreach( $order as $key => $item){    
  echo $item[$key]->item_qty;
  echo $item[$key]->entry_id;
}
```