# Loop trough object in PHP

Tags: php, loops, object

I read trought [How to loop through objects in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664208/how-to-loop-through-objects-in-php)
But still don't get it to work

Has someone an idea? Here is my php

```
$Topic_OBJ = json_decode($this->api_local_get($url));
$Text_IDS = "";
    
foreach ($Topic_OBJ as $obj) {
    $Text_IDS .= $obj->Text->Text_id.",";
}
```

$Topic_OBJ looks like

```
{
        "TextContainer_id": 339131662,
        "Text": [
            {
                "Text_id": 794887707,
                "TextContainer_id": 339131662
            },
            {
                "Text_id": 794887711,
                "TextContainer_id": 339131662
            }
        ]
    }
```

But Text_IDS is only ",," but should be "794887707,794887711,"

Can someone help me please?
thanks rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should loop over the `$Topic_OBJ->Text` array instead like so...

```
<?php

$Topic_OBJ = json_decode($this->api_local_get($url));
$Text_IDS = "";
    
foreach ($Topic_OBJ->Text as $text) {
    $Text_IDS .= $text->Text_id.",";
}
```